# Get values of a single attribute from an instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I have an instance variable `@items` which i get from doing`@items = Item.all` inside a controller action. The `Item` class looks like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :weight, :color, :price
  validates :color, presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
end
```

What i would like to do is to get the values of the `:id` attributes of all the items in`@items` the controller action in which i'm trying to get the ids looks like this:

```
def get_item_ids
  @items = Item.all
  item_ids = ??? ## i'm stuck here
end
```

How can get `item_ids` as an array of `:id` attributes of items inside `@items` ?

Comment: `Item.select(:id)`.. would work I think.

Comment: For a better use of the performances, use pluck: `item_ids = Item.scoped.pluck(:id)`

Comment: Sorry, if i was not clear but i'm asking if i can get item_ids from `@items`, for example if can do `item_ids = @items.????`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need the ids and not the entire object itself, MrYoshiji's answer is best:

```
item_ids = Item.scoped.pluck(:id)
```

If, however, you already have a collection of items in @items then you can do this:

```
item_ids = @items.map(&:id)
```